# inconsistency of data using FQL - Table stream

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

I'm using **FQL** to get the post recently modified to exactly 10 minutes ago, the FQL used is as follows:

```
SELECT post_id, message, created_time, likes.count, likes.user_likes, comments.count, actor_id 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id=[My FanPage ID] and updated_time > [UNIXTIME (sysdate - 10min)]
```

Executing this FQL from Guatemala server returns all posts correctly, running the query from a server Nicaragua many posts are excluded.

What could be happening?

Comment: Any difference in the Access token used to query?

Comment: I´m using the same access token.

Answer (score 0):

The facebook's server GMT is 00:00. Try to adjust the time.

My GMT is -3, I had to query **strtotime("-3 hours")** when I got this same problem.